# AWS S3 JS SDK to upload multiple files from a browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-sdk-js

I want to use the AWS S3 JS SDK to upload multiple files from a browser. I can get one file just fine, but can't get multiple. When I select mulitple files, the last file is the only one to get uploaded. Here's the code:

```
//head    
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.213.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

//body 
<input type="file" id="file-chooser" multiple />
<button id="upload-button">Upload to S3</button>
<div id="results"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: '###'
});

AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {
    if (err) alert(err);
    console.log(AWS.config.credentials);
});

var bucketName = 'c2networkingfiles'; // Enter your bucket name
var bucket = new AWS.S3({
    params: {
        Bucket: bucketName
    }
});

var fileChooser = document.getElementById('file-chooser');
var button = document.getElementById('upload-button');
var results = document.getElementById('results');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var fileArr = fileChooser.files;
  if (fileArr[0]) {
    for (k=0; k<fileArr.length; k++) {
      var file = fileArr[k];
      var fileName = file.name;

      // test to see if file already exists
      var objKey2 = 'testing/' + file.name;
      var objE = new AWS.S3();
      var params2 = {
          Bucket: bucketName,
          Key: objKey2
      };
      objE.headObject(params2, function(err, data) {
        if (data) {
          results.innerHTML = 'File is present. Uploaded on ' + data.LastModified;
          //console.log(data);
        } else {
          //results.innerHTML = '';
          var objKey = 'testing/' + file.name;
          var params = {
              Key: objKey,
              ContentType: file.type,
              Body: file,
              ACL: 'public-read'
          };

          bucket.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
              if (err) {
                results.innerHTML = 'ERROR: ' + err;
              } else {
                //listObjs();
                results.append('SUCCESS! ' + fileName + ' uploaded. <br />');
              }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  } else {
      results.append('Nothing to upload.');
  }
}, false);
</script>
```

The original code example didn't have the loop and I'm wondering if this isn't working right because there isn't a mechanism to wait until the first file has finished before the loop starts the next upload.

If this is the answer, is there a way to check the upload status and wait until the first file is complete before the loop is allowed to continue?

If this isn't the answer, what else could be happening?